# adding colors to posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Sometimes questions don't contain code(which is not bad except if the code is necessary) but I found I have to write a wall of text which is ugly, I know there are headers,horizontal lines,code blocks,and more but none of them are colored except code blocks and without code, your whole question is black , I tried copying and pasting a colored word and it turned black, black is good but when your question is long, it's not beautiful .
So why not adding colors to our posts or accepting the copy and paste of a colored word.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211998/can-we-change-the-color-of-comments-or-questions-text

Comment: You're not here to make beautiful posts, just understandable ones. Formatting your questions/answers properly and using proper English is more than enough. Use paragraphs. No need for a "wall of text."

Answer (score 22):

[image: no]

---

(my point being that colors are <red>ridiculously</red> easy to abuse and would quickly get <green>annoying</green> and make us look like a <blue>forum</blue>.)

<sub>answer copied from https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/91/39. but that's okay, since I posted that one as well</sub>

Comment: Lol,I was suprised when I saw "Please no that would be terrible" in rainbow colours. I pressed the "edit" button to see how you've done that and oh! you fooled me!

Answer (score 14):

> So why not adding colors to our posts

Because then low quality posts will light up like christmas trees as the OP tries to use every which colour to get attention.

Really, we already have enough issues with people `abusing` ***every*** *formatting* **faux-pas** in the book as it is.