# Changing review test warning colors to increase the impact

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits

When reviewing stack posts, we sometimes encounter to test reviews which we pass or fail. either way, there will be a **Congratulations!** or **Stop! Look and Listen** message in front of us. *Both in black color*

What I'm suggesting maybe is not a big deal, but in my opinion will **Psychologically** increase the impact on the reviewer, and make him attention more and be more careful about what he's doing.

I've prepared an example.

[image]

In this picture you may feel what I'm talking about.

Green color makes me feel more excited about what I did right and red makes me feel warned and more careful.

I don't know the reason why this messages are all in black. maybe they don't want a [Christmas tree](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281335/2263683) or whatever.(*well, this is not post coloring suggestion, so there wouldn't make a Christmas tree*)

But doesn't anybody agree with me?

Comment: So you get downvotes for suggesting something to improve the site!

Comment: Downvotes mean: I don't agree with this feature-request. Don't feel bad about different opinions, nothing wrong with your post.

Comment: Keep in mind that colors don't have consistent meanings across different cultures. Even though the website is in English, we do have an international audience and we can't assume that everyone has the same cultural background. Aside from that, do you really think that these messages are failing to have an impact as they are currently rendered?

Comment: It only makes sense to do it the other way around.  Programmers are braniacs that are *not* used to failing simple tests.  That message seriously pisses them off, many complaints about it at meta.  Waving a red flag in front of the bull just makes it more mad.

Comment: @CodyGray Psychology is a complicated thing. A red warning may stop some people to just click on review buttons and start really reviewing the posts.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the uppercase "STOP" is already deterring enough. There is no need to add colors everywhere.
You should carefully read the message and try to learn from it, regardless of its color.

Please don't feel bad about the downvotes. On a post tagged with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), they just mean "I disagree with this feature suggestion".

Comment: On posts tagged with [meta-tag:discussion], downvotes just mean that users don't like the discussion and don't want to have it. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for the edit. Well what I meant to say is "I disagree with this feature suggestion" :)

Comment: I knew what you meant. I just think it's funny that people are always talking about how downvotes mean blah blah blah on Meta if you use a certain tag. But really, downvotes on Meta just mean "I don't like this," no matter which tag is used.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the opinion. I still believe that In a site where *almost* everything is black, a colored message can gets more focus and attentions.